# Why is it possible to declare the same var two times using for-loop?

Tags: variables, for-loop, go, var, variable-declaration

I was trying Go on http://tour.golang.org/, and I saw that it was possible to declarate two times the same var using := in for loop.
The output is the same with the Go compiler.

**Here is my test :** (see the var i, it was declared two times)

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    i := "Hello"
    a := 0
    for a < 2 {
        fmt.Println(i)
        i := "World !"
        fmt.Println(i)
        a++
    }       
}
```

**Output :**

> Hello
>
> World !
>
> Hello
>
> World !

Can someone explain that ?

Comment: New scope, new game. Basically like in every other language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) `i :=  ...` will overshadow the same variable declared outside of the scope of the `for` loop **[block](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blocks)**.

> Each "[`if`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#If_statements)", "[`for`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements)", and "[`switch`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements)" statement is considered to be in its own implicit block

You can see more at "[Go gotcha #1: variable shadowing within inner scope due to use of `:=` operator](https://developmentality.wordpress.com/2014/03/03/go-gotcha-1-variable-shadowing-within-inner-scope-due-to-use-of-operator/)"

It refers to this [goNuts discussion](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/golang-nuts/132kx1r460/go-nuts-shadowing-a-proposal-to-improve-visibility-usage-analysis).

A short variable declaration can redeclare the same variable within a block, but since `i` is also declared *outside* the for block, it keeps its value outside said block ([different scope](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope)).

Answer (score 1):

The first i has been defined inside the braces ({}) of main function wheras the second i is declared within the scope of the for loop. The name is same but the scope is different.